# Karma of executioners

Tags: karma

How does the karma of an executioner work? Although they are only doing their job, does it amount to bad karma? What if an executioner has to kill a wrongly accused person? And what if the executioner sympathizes with the person he is meant to kill? How does their karma work in those scenarios?

Answer (score 3):

Executioners are just doing their job ( `Nitya Karma` )

He does not gets any bad karmic effect since he is not killing any wrongly accused person purposefully.

If he is killing any jiva purposefully then he is definitely get into bad karmic effects.

Comment: Could you please provide any source for your answer?

Comment: @Suhasini listen to this amazing monk.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77yXJVImP5U

Comment: It just like soldiers not accruing any Karma

Answer (score 0):

If the executioner does not self identify with his job, and does it only as a duty without apathy or sympathy for the people killed, then no karma comes to him. Otherwise, some Karmic results will definitely come back to him.